# Custom File Extension in C++

Tags: c++, windows, file-extension

How is it possible to create a custom extension in C++? I know it can be rather easily achieved in C#, but I have yet to see something like this done in C++.

Well, what I mean is something like, how I can write something so that, if I have a file .xyz and a program that read .xyz files, Windows opens them up automatically?

Comment: Uuh, you mean naming something name.xyz and then representing it as your own format :) ?

Comment: There are several things I can think of that you might mean, but the answer to all of them is: the same way as in C#. So can you specify a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff513920(v=vs.85).aspx . You clearly want to know about Windows, so the fact it's different for every OS doesn't matter much.

There are several parts to this. First, you need to write code that implements some specific COM interfaces. Then, you put entries in the registry that tell Windows where to find the code you have written. Depending on your needs, that might just be to launch your app and open the file, but it might also include the thumbnail that Windows Explorer shows in tile view (word docs and .txt files all look the same, but jpgs have a thumbnail that's the mini image), the preview that Windows Explorer can show on the side, custom properties and so on. All of these involve an interaction between the shell and your application, through COM interfaces that you implement, and that the shell calls because it sees in the registry that you have written them.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you can do it either through the `assoc` command line utility (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490865.aspx) or perform the action directly in the registry (see e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776871.aspx).

On Linux systems for every file type you have to register it's MIME type and then register a handler for that MIME type. Refer to http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mimetypes-0.html.en for a comprehensive overview.

I don't know enough about Mac OS to be of any help with that one, I have to admit.

**edit:** I Just remembered how it works on Mac OS: In your application bundle (`*.app/` directory), create a file called `Contents/Info.plist` with contents following the [property-list specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW1) and create the entries for the [`CFBundleDocumentTypes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1) element.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't do in general. The first problem is that it depends on the operation system how to handle this. And even there it mostly is not the programm that decides who opens which file but the OS. And your OS simply does not nessesary know wheather you a have a specific program or not. All you can do is advice the OS in some kind of installation prozess that it should use your program to open specific files. I don't use windows, but probably it means adding some registry entries.